# How to count observations in a SAS dataset using proc sql?h

Tags: sas

I need to update the below code to do two things:
1) `sourceh.group2` has a variable called Type that divides the dataset into four groups. I need to count the number of observations in each of these groups separately. How can I update my program to do that?
2) I would like to create a new dataset that has the number of observations. The below program gives me the number in the log page but instead I'd like to create a new dataset. How can I program it?

If there is a more efficeint way to do these other than `proc sql` that would also be very useful, it is a large dataset.

Thank you!

```
proc sql noprint;
   select count(*) into :nobs
   from sourceh.group2; 
quit;
%put Obs in data set: &nobs;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you just need to create a table that has type, the count of observations with that type, and group it by type. For your second question, you do the same thing but without the groups (since you only want the total number of observations):

```
proc sql;
    create table count_by_type as select
        type, cap, count(*) as count
        from sourceh.group2
        group by type, cap;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table count_all as select
        count(*) as count
        from sourceh.group2;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first suggestion worked great, that's what I needed. Actually, in addition to type there is another variable called cap (that divides the dataset into three). I would like to count the observations by type and cap together, ie 3 cap * 4 type = 12 groups. How can I update your first code to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: I think my edit addresses this - let me know if not.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `PROC SUMMARY`.  It will let you get counts by TYPE, CAP, both or neither in a single run.

```
 proc summary data=have ;
   class type cap ;
   output out=counts ;
 run;
```

The variable _TYPE_ will let you tell you which class variables contributed to the table.  With two class variables you will have four values of _TYPE_ .  00 will have the overall count, 1 will have the count by level of CAP, 2 ('10'b) will have the count by level of TYPE and 3 ('11'b) will have the values by levels of TYPE and CAP.